# How to draw an image from absolute paths

Tags: html, image, src

I'm trying to draw an image as follows, but the image just doesn't show:

```
<img src="file:///var/www/html/projects/wordpress_projects/wordpress/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/pages/competition_antitrust/images/competition_antitrust/competition-law.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

What could be the problem?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The file is probably getting blocked because you're attempting to reference it directly from your PC's file system instead of a server of some sort. Open up Dev Tools (F12) to confirm.

Comment: You most likely simple want `/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/pages/competition_antitrust/images/competition_antitrust/competition-law.jpg`